# Why commutator transforms like a vector

Tags: transformation, vector-fields

Let's define
\begin{equation}
    [X, Y]^i=X^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} Y^i-Y^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} X^i
\end{equation}
Then for coordinate transformation
$x^{i\prime}(x^1,x^2,\ldots,x^n)$:
\begin{equation}
X^{j\prime}=\dfrac{\partial x^{j\prime}}{\partial x^i}X^i;\quad Y^{k\prime}=\dfrac{\partial x^{k\prime}}{\partial x^l}Y^l;\quad \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{m\prime}}=\dfrac{\partial x^n}{\partial x^{m\prime}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}
\end{equation}
I'm getting:
\begin{equation}
    [X,Y]^{k\prime}=\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{j\prime}}{\partial x^i}X^i\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x^n}{\partial x^{j\prime}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{k\prime}}{\partial x^l}Y^l\right)-\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{j\prime}}{\partial x^l}Y^l\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x^n}{\partial x^{j\prime}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{k\prime}}{\partial x^l}X^l\right)
\end{equation}
But if commutator is also vector, I should get something like:
\begin{equation}
[X,Y]^{k\prime}=\dfrac{\partial x^{k\prime}}{\partial x^i}[X, Y]^i
\end{equation}
It doesn't seem to appear here

Comment: am I even going in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Note the chain rule implies e.g.$$\frac{\partial x^{j\prime}}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial x^n}{\partial x^{j\prime}}=\frac{\partial x^n}{\partial x^i}=\delta_i^n.$$

Comment: Oh, thank you, it makes my problem much easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it:
\begin{equation}
    [X,Y]^{i\prime}=\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{j\prime}}{\partial x^k}X^k\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x^n}{\partial x^{j\prime}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{i\prime}}{\partial x^l}Y^l\right)-\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{j\prime}}{\partial x^k}Y^k\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x^n}{\partial x^{j\prime}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{i\prime}}{\partial x^l}X^l\right)=
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}  =\left(\delta^n_kX^k\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{i\prime}}{\partial x^l}Y^l\right)-\left(\delta^n_kY^k\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{i\prime}}{\partial x^l}X^l\right)=
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}  =X^n\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{i\prime}}{\partial x^l}Y^l\right)-Y^n\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\left(\dfrac{\partial x^{i\prime}}{\partial x^l}X^l\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}  =\dfrac{\partial x^{i\prime}}{\partial x^l}\left(X^n\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}Y^l-Y^n\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}X^l\right)+\left(Y^lX^n\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\dfrac{\partial x^{i\prime}}{\partial x^l}-X^lY^n\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\dfrac{\partial x^{i\prime}}{\partial x^l}\right)
\end{equation}
Second bracket equals zero while the first equals:
\begin{equation}
    \dfrac{\partial x^{i\prime}}{\partial x^l}[X,Y]^l
\end{equation}